# Error with String[] and writeObject

Tags: java

In writeObject of FileOutputStream we declare one String Array that time error are occurs.
My Code is

`writeObject(String[] str {"1"});`

Comment: Please visit the [ask] page and [edit] your question. As of right now, you aren't even asking a question. Please be specific in what you want from us :)

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, `1` is not a String .

Also, your syntax is not correct to pass the array , try this way :

```
yourObjectOutputStream.writeObject(new String[] {"1"});
```

Or if you prefer

```
String[] str = new String[] {"1"};
yourObjectOutputStream.writeObject(str);
```